# Grep specific part of string from another file

Tags: awk, grep

I want to grep the first three digits of numbers in 1.txt from the first three digits after zeros in 2.txt.

cat 1.txt

```
 23456
 12345
 6789
```

cat 2.txt

```
 20000023485 xxx888
 20000012356 xxx888
 20000067234 xxx234
```

Expected output

```
 20000023485 xxx888
 20000012356 xxx888
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Well yes, but obviously wont work **grep "$(awk '{num=substr($1,1,3); print num}' 1.txt)" "$(awk '{num=substr($1,3,7); sub(/^0+/, "", num); print num}' 2.txt)"**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk 'FNR==NR {a[substr($1,0,3)];next}
             {match($1, /0+/);
             if(substr($1, RSTART+RLENGTH,3) in a)print}' 1.txt 2.txt
```

`{a[substr($1,0,3)];next}` - stores the first 3 characters in an associative array.

`match($1, /0+/);if(substr($1, RSTART+RLENGTH,3) in a)`
Matches the 3 charaacters after the series of zeroes and checks whether these 3 characters are present in the associative array that was created earlier and prints the whole line if match is found.

Answer (score 1):

Try this with grep:

```
grep -f <(sed 's/^\(...\).*/00\1/' file1) file2
```

Output:

```
20000023485 xxx
20000012356 xxx
```

Comment: Very smart usage of grep, but I think it wasn't what the OP asked for (matching the first 3 digits after the zeros in 2.txt). Maybe `grep -f <(grep -o '^...' 1.txt | sed 's/^/000/g') 2.txt` ?

Answer (score 0):

grep -f will match a series of patterns from the given file, one per line.  But first you need to turn 1.txt into the patterns you want.  In your case, you want the first three characters of each line of 1.txt, after zeros:  00*234, 00*123, etc.  (I'm assuming you want at least one zero.)

```
sed -e 's/^\(...\).*$/00*\1/' 1.txt > 1f.txt
grep -f 1f.txt 2.txt
```